# Texture will be lost when any interrupt happen

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, native, android-ndk

I detected the textures will be lost when any interrupt happen.

For exsample, i received a phone call and then back to the opengles activity. The textures i loaded will be lost.

How can i save these textures?

ps: These textures loaded on Native C.

Answer (score 0):

The textures are being lost along with the context when onPause is called. It's difficult to catch because the context is recreated when onResume is called. You will need to recreate the textures.